# How to fill empty space when component is not visible or hidden?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have several components into `BorderPane` which can be visible or not using checkbox.
When I set component not to be visible I get empty space which I want to fill by resizing the next component. What are the available options to configure the components to fill the empty space when component is set to `.setVisible(false);`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to call `setManaged(false)` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution `setManaged(false)` saves me a lot of problems.

Answer (score 10):

You can take advantage of bindings to set managed property automatically based on visibility.
E.g. `component.managedProperty().bind(component.visibleProperty());`